# Calculating delay time in Milliseconds

Tags: percentages

Alright, this might be an odball question, so here goes. This question is part music, part mathematics, but mostly mathematics.

I am an audio engineer and I want precise delay times in certain pan positions in the stereo spectrum.
I am trying to calculate ***delay time in milliseconds***, I already have the main formula for calculating times for certain note lengths, but there are a few that are quite tricky and beyond my knowledgeable grasp and I am unsure how I would go about figuring out how to calculate these values. Here is what I have so far; please bare with me, as I am doing the best I can to provide as much information as possible.

- There are 60,000 milliseconds in a minute
- We need to take into consideration the **BPM** (*Beats Per Minute*) of the current track
- By default, all calculations result in ***quarter note*** values

So, the formula is:

- **60,000** / **BPM** (**140** *for example*) = **428.5** ***ms***, you always round upwards, so we actually end up with **429** ***ms***

So that is the basic formula with a default note value of quarter notes, as **1** quarter note = **1** beat

*But, what if we want a delay time other than quarter note values?*
To answer this, we first need to understand basic note comparisons

- A Basic quarter note would have a value of **100%**
- Next we have ***8th notes***, you can fit ***2*** 8th notes in a quarter note, making an 8th note have a value of **50%** or ***0.50*** more precisely
- Next, 16th notes, you can fit **4** in a quarter note, giving a 16th note a value of **0.25**
- 32nd notes, **8** in a quarter, a value of **0.125**
- 64th notes, **16** in a quarter, a value of **0.0625**

Let's do another calculation with a different note, say 16th notes

- 60,000 / 140 = 429 x 0.25 = **107** ***ms***

Here is where it gets tricky, we also have dotted notes, and triplet notes indicated by (**.** & **T**)

Let's start with **dotted** notes

- **.8th**, if you compare a .8th note to a regular quarter note, you will see that it's 75% of the length of a quarter note or equivalent in length to **3** *regular 16th notes*, making 75%, or more precisely **0.75** (Please refer to the chart I have created below)

This is where I stop as I am unable to figure out what percentage or in decimal form the values of the rest of the notes would be in comparison to a regular quarter note or **4** 16th notes (using 4 16th notes as a comparison is easier in the chart I have created)

So with that said, I would like to know the values for:

- .16th, .32nd, .64th  (These would be the dotted notes)
- 8th**T**, 16th**T**, 32nd**T** & 64th**T** (These would be triplet notes)

If you would like to inquire more information I will do my best, but I am not sure what I can provide

[Here is the chart I have created for note comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfFzr.jpg)

Comment: I have done a little work, using the fact that all math is just patterns. Using 140BPM and using dotted notes we can see that, delay times for .16th, .32nd & 64th would be 160, 80 & 40 respectively, but what would the percentages be for the formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dotted note takes 50% longer than the plain note.  For example, a dotted eighth note at 140 bpm (quarter note rate) would require a delay of 
$$
\frac{60}{140}\cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1.5 = 0.32142857...
$$
seconds, or $321.42857..$ msec.

A triplet of eighth notes contains $3$ notes in the space of $2$ normal eighth notes, so the delay is 2/3 of of the usual.  So a triplet of eighth notes at 140 bpm would require
$$
\frac{60}{140} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 \cdot \frac{1}{3} = 0.142857142...
$$ seconds, or $142.857142..$ msec.  That is, there are three eight notes per quarter note, so delay needed is 1/3 the delay for a quarter note.

For other notes, just change the $1/2$ factors above to the appropriate power-of-2 fraction (e.g., 1/4 for sixteenth notes, 1/8 for 32nd notes, etc.)

Comment: Okay, to clarify, replace the 1/2 fraction to 1/4 per say in the triplet algorithm, you would end up with a value of 71ms? If this is true, wouldn't it be easier to just divide the result by 2 each time?

Comment: That is the same thing.  Do it however you like.  Cheers!